# How do you say in Spanish, "I am waiting for my boyfriend to open the door"?

Tags: traducción, conjugación

I am having trouble with the construcción of these types of sentences. Is it "Estoy esperando a que mi novio abre la puerta"? Or do you use the unconjugated *abrir*?

Answer (score 10):

That's almost right. You need the subjunctive mood for *abrir* (i.e. *abra*)  because you're describing an irrealis situation. The correct sentence would be:

> Estoy esperando (a) que mi novio abra la puerta.

It is common to drop the preposition *a* in some countries such as Argentina or Chile, as per the comments, while it is kept in Spain.

Comment: Just a question, is it also right if you drop the *a* preposition?

Comment: I cannot comment about "right" (I always despised the Spanish class at school), but in Argentina  (where I grew up), no one would use the "a".

Comment: @VladimirNu I don't know if it would be grammatically wrong, but I wouldn't drop it. Note how the meaning changes in the sentence *Espero a que mi novio abra la puerta*, wich expresses a fact, compared to *Espero que mi novio abra la puerta*, which expresses a wish or hope. When *esperar* is conjugated in a continuous tense (*estoy esperando*), it isn't generally understood as a wish, but I still would only drop the preposition *a* before a *que* when expressing a wish or hope.

Comment: @MartinArgerami that's what I meant, in Chile we also don't use it.

Comment: @MartinArgerami It may be a regional thing then. In Spain the construction with *a* is more common. It's good to know that's not the case in other regions!

Comment: @Yay: that said, I agree with your argument. In Argentina people wrongly  (but commonly) would say both cases the same.

Comment: The same with "debe". Almost no one says "debe de" to distinguish a suposition from an order.

Comment: @MartinAregami People do that in Spain too, but here they say *deber de* or just *deber* inconsistently when speaking about both orders and suppositions.

Comment: @Yay I asked the question because I believe that usage is valid only in Spain. That means only about 10% of the native spanish speaking countries. Just wanted to confirm that, would like to hear from people in other countries as well.

Comment: @VladimirNu Fair enough. If more people chip in I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: @Yay I'm not saying is wrong, there are just two different ways.

Comment: If you read the definition of [esperar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GYqGDs8) in the DRAE (yeah, the DLE, whatever), meanings 3 (transitive) and 4 (intransitive) are applicable here. They are very similar and, in fact, in this case they mean almost the same. So I think that using *a* or not is a question of personal taste. Being Spanish, I find Yay's proposal more natural, but I understand that other people prefer not using *a* and I would not find it weird.

Comment: I think "esperar a que" (intransitive meaning) is "to wait"; in contrast, "esperar que" (transitive meaning) is "to hope", as @Gorpik said.

Comment: @Jdamian I didn't say so :) "To hope" is meaning 1 in the definition, but here it would be meaning 3.